# Understanding post edits on SO

Tags: discussion, edits

I was just editing a question, and when I tried to submit I got a usual message another edit is going to be reviewed and mine will be placed in the queue.

Does this mean when I tried to submit initially it was placed in the queue OR I have to wait and try again a little later?

I'm not sure if I understand the editing post aspect correctly.

Comment: What was the exact text of the message?

Comment: You have no pending suggested edits on SO.

Comment: I think it was the along the lines of this"Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed." And on submit it was in red and did not submit...I cant recall the exact message now

Comment: You can't submit an edit to be reviewed if there's already an edit from someone else waiting for review.

Comment: So if i move away from the page, how can I find the post later to check the edit?

Comment: @Harry: Bookmark it? Leave it open in a tab? Save to a snippet program or service? Put it in Pocket or the like? SE provides no features for this, but it's not a unique problem.